# Dynamically allocate lines (which comes from a struct) into file in C

Tags: c

I'll try to be quick and clear. What I'm trying to do is a sort of "database", a chain of restaurants got many locations.

The program writes a file "sedi.dat" in binary which in the program is initialized with 100 empty records which refers to the struct "ristorante"

```
typedef struct {
    int codice;
    char sede[12];
    int posti, liberi, occupati;
} ristorante;

ristorante buffer = { 0, "", 0, 0, 0};
//fopen stuff
for (i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(ristorante), 1, pointer);
};
```

So now I have 100 binary rows that basically say `{ 0, "", 0, 0, 0};`. What I want to do with this "formatted" file, is to fill it with rows gained input by the user.

I created a function to do this void create_table (FILE *pointer); what it basically (should) do is receive the file pointer, create 2 empty buffer (which I use for storing data from input and the file, but I could change it) then cycle until the pointer reaches the end of file or the if inside the cycle gives flag=1 (which happens when the row starting with the first 0 in the struct is found), else it increase the counter and move the offset counter*sizeof(struct) and then load what it's written with fread!

Now, the matter is that this function is able only to load the first row (with multiple tries it only writes the 1st row), it is uncapable to seek the other rows! What I was thinking to do is:

```
read row
if (first value of struct!=0) {
    ++counter;
    seek next row
}
else {
    write input row with increasing first value starting from 1 to 100
}
```

I tried and tried and searched and tried, for 2 days, but now it's time to ask for help!
The program menu

1. prints all the rows (I eliminated an if by which if the row was empty it was not printed)
2. insert new rows
3. and
4. must be further checked to work properly
5. exit

Hope I've been clear, now I'm in your hands :)

Here's the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define def 100

typedef struct {
    int codice;
    char sede[12];
    int posti, liberi, occupati;
} ristorante;

typedef struct {
    int number, posti, codice;
} prenotazione;

int scelta_menu (void);
int new_prenotazione (prenotazione max, FILE *pointer, int i);
void stampa_tabella (FILE *pointer);
void create_table (FILE *pointer);


int main () {
    prenotazione max; 
    int scelta, i;
    int conta_entry=0;
    FILE *pointer;
    ristorante buffer = { 0, "", 0, 0, 0};

    while((scelta=scelta_menu())!=5) {
        if((pointer=fopen("sedi.dat", "rb+"))==NULL)  {

            printf("\nTabella sedi assente, ne verra' creata una nuova.\n\n");
            pointer=fopen("sedi.dat", "wb+");

            for (i=0; i<def; ++i) {
                fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(ristorante), 1, pointer);
            }

        }
        else {
            printf("\nFile caricato con successo!");

            switch (scelta) {

            case 1: 
                 stampa_tabella(pointer);
                 break;

            case 2: 
                 create_table(pointer);
             break;

            case 3: 
                 conta_entry=new_prenotazione(max, pointer, conta_entry);
                 break;

         case 4: 
                  printf("La prenotazione con il maggior numero di posti e' la #%d per #%d posti\n\n", max.codice, max.posti);
                  break;

         default:
                  printf("\nScelta non corretta!\n\n");
                  break;

            }

        }

        fclose(pointer);

    }
    return 0;
}



int scelta_menu (void) {
    //system("cls");
    int scelta;
    printf("\n\nMenu Prenotazione:\n\n1 - Visualizza Tabella\n2 - Crea/Aggiorna Tabella\n3 - Nuova prenotazione\n4 - Visualizza prenotazione  piu' grande\n5 - Esci\n\n---> ");
    scanf("%d", &scelta);

    return(scelta);
}

void create_table (FILE *pointer) {

    int i=0;
        int flag=0;
ristorante buffer = { 0, "", 0, 0, 0};

    ristorante buffer1 = { 0, "", 0, 0, 0};

    printf("\nInserisci il nome della sede ed il numero totale dei posti: ");

    scanf("%s%d", buffer.sede, &buffer.posti);
buffer.liberi=buffer.posti;

    printf("\n\n\n%-6s%8s        %s     %s      %s\n", "Cod.", "Sede", "Posti", "Occupati", "Liberi");

    printf("%-6d%10s         %d         %d             %d\n", buffer.codice, buffer.sede, buffer.posti, buffer.occupati, buffer.liberi);

     do {

        fread(&buffer1, sizeof(ristorante), 1, pointer);

        if (buffer1.codice!=0) {

        flag=0;

        ++i;

        fseek(pointer, (i)*sizeof(ristorante), SEEK_SET);

        }

        else {

        flag=1;

        printf("\nEsisto...\n");

        buffer.codice=buffer1.codice+1;

        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(ristorante), 1, pointer);

        }

    } while(!feof(pointer) && flag!=1);

     fclose(pointer);

     system ("pause");
}



    void stampa_tabella (FILE *pointer) {

    ristorante buffer = { 0, "", 0, 0, 0};

    printf("\n\n\n%4s%8s        %s     %s      %s\n", "Cod.", "Sede", "Posti", "Occupati", "Liberi");

    while(!feof(pointer)) {

     //fseek(pointer, i*sizeof(ristorante), SEEK_SET);

     fread(&buffer, sizeof(ristorante), 1, pointer);

     // if (buffer.codice!=0) {
 printf("%d%10s         %d         %d             %d\n", buffer.codice, 

     buffer.sede, buffer.posti, buffer.occupati, buffer.liberi);

    //}
     }

    fclose(pointer);
    } //fine stampa tabella
    int new_prenotazione (prenotazione max, FILE *pointer, int i) {
prenotazione buffer;
ristorante rist;


    printf("\nInserisci il codice della sede ed il numero dei posti da prenotare: ");
        scanf("%d%d", &buffer.codice, &buffer.posti);
        //sposto puntatore file

    fseek(pointer, (buffer.codice)*sizeof(ristorante), SEEK_SET);

    //legge record

    fread(&rist, sizeof(ristorante), 1, pointer);

    // errore se la sede non esiste

    if(rist.codice!=buffer.codice) {

        printf("\n\nLa sede %d non esiste!\n\n", buffer.codice);

     }

     //altrimenti aggiorna il record del file sede


       else {

      ++i;

        buffer.number=i;

        rist.liberi-=buffer.posti;

        rist.occupati+=buffer.posti;

        printf("\nPrenotazione effettuata! ");

        printf("\nCodice Sede Posti Occupati Liberi\n");

        fwrite(&rist, sizeof(ristorante), 1, pointer);
        }

    if(buffer.posti>=max.posti) {
            max=buffer;


      }


       rewind(pointer);
        return (i);
    } //fine new_record

     //end**
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad formatting of the cod, I just manually filled it with spaces in order to make the markes of the site happy...

Comment: That makes it difficult to read however, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'm a newbe on this site...well, I've done my best to divide main by functions...it should be more readable! I tried to avoid this by focusing in the first part of the post my trouble, why the while() in --- void create_table (FILE *pointer) --- doesn't update the file pointer to seek the other records! Anyway the code should compile...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're asking for is [random access file I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html). That, combined with fixed-length records, permits reading and writing individual entries in the file without having to read/write the entire file. You will probably need to maintain an explicit index (or several) to support that.

Note: If by *insert* you mean inserting between existing entries, that's messy. As with an array, to insert a record you have to first move all the other records up to make space for it, which means reading and rewriting them all (and making sure not to let them step on each other in the process of doing so.) Depending on what you're doing and why, the better answer is probably to append the new record to the end of the file, and worry about ordering only in the indexes.

Deletion can be handled by removing a record from the live-data indexes and adding it to an "empty record" list for possible reuse (rather than appending to the end of the file).

Basically, it's the same set of issues as memory management and/or handling an array of fixed-length strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responce keshlam! No I didn't want to "move" a record between 2 already existing record, I just wanted to insert a record (in a preformatted file) calculating live the index value of that record! 

I've already implemented codes whom did what you exactly wrote using explicit index given in input by the user with the rest of the data of structure. Basically this time I tried (to practice) to so the same thin but using an implicit index auto-updated! So from what is your experience, is it possible or just a useless work?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by "an implicit index auto-updated".

Comment: Like in databases, i use the first field of the struct "ristorante" ristorante.codice like a primary key, the index of the record in my file. What I mean for implicit auto-updated index is that the program reads the last record, checks its field 'codice' and then auto-increments it by 1 to use it like .codice field of the next record inserted by the user and written in the file in the next position after the previous last record!

Comment: Of course, barring deletions, you actually know the record number of the last record (file length divided by record length), and many filesystems can give you the length without reading the file or spending space in the file on record numbers. And record number is in many cases not an especially interesting primary key. So: Obviously possible, dubiously useful, whether it actually makes sense in your specific case is probably out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought it was useful in case the file was opened again and someone wanted to add some new data. So what you suggest is, don't initialize the file, to get the size of file and of structure and then calculate how many records have been written? 

Thanks a lot for your useful tooltips, I'm a beginner in programming and these are only excercises' programs to practice and make mistakes until I learn enough to say: now I can start calling me a programmer!